# Error in c when iterating: use of undeclared identifier i

Tags: c, cs50

I am creating a program that will ask a command line argument from the user, and the user need to input only integers as the argv[1]. It should reject any input other than integers. My code is as below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[] )
string s = argv[1];
    for (int i = 0; n = strlen(s); i< n; i++)
    {
        if(!( isdigit(s[i])) )
        {
            printf("All numbers: correct input");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Else print a prompt asking for a plaintext to cipher
    else
    {
        string p = get_string("Your text here: ");
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

Running the above code throws me an error: error: ***use of undeclared identifier 'i'    for (int i = 0; n = strlen(s); i< n; i++)***

Where do I do wrong here and how do I fix this? Thanks.

Sorry if my questions seem stupid, I am still a newbie learning here and know absolutely nothing about C before. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Where's the `main` function?

Comment: Oh sorry, Forgot to include them above. I'll edit it.

Comment: That's not complete code (you've got loops in global scope, with no `main` function). And you've somehow put four statements into a `for` loop, which isn't legal either (that first semi-colon should probably be a comma). And you're calling `strlen` on a `string`, the latter of which isn't a thing in C, and the C++ version doesn't make sense for use with `strlen`. Your braces don't match either (`for`/`else` is a thing in Python, but not in C/C++). There's a million problems here.

Comment: You are using 3 semicolons in `for (int i = 0; n = strlen(s); i< n; i++)` Change it to `for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i< n; i++)`

Comment: Using `get_string()` and the type `string` smacks strongly of being part of CS50 (SO tag [tag:cs50]; SE site [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/)).  It's simpler to include the `<cs50.h>` header so that `string` and `get_string()` are declared than to try disguising it.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje, I fixed the code as per your advice but a new error message now shows this error: expected expression else . Any advice?

Comment: @user71812 what compiler are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for the explanation. Not familiar with CS50, was very confused.

Comment: With the number of problems in the shown code, you would be better off taking not one but several steps back, according to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ May recommend to find a HelloWorld and tutorials on basic structures like conditional statements and loops? Put an `if` into the HelloWorld and make it work. Add an `else` and make it work. Add a `for` and make it work. In this the "and make it work" are very important. They will allow you to always know where the error is, even if you do not know the error....

Comment: ... because if something worked, but fails after a simple change. Then the change contains the error. This way step from working simple thing to working slightly complexer thing, to finally the working thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C89 compiler you will need to put the delarations at the top of the scope block, so the variable i has to be declared before the for loop.

Try this if your using C89:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[] ){
 string s = argv[1];
 int i = 0;
 int n = strlen(s);
 for (; i< n; i++)
    {
        if(!( isdigit(s[i])) )
        {
            printf("All numbers: correct input");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Else print a prompt asking for a plaintext to cipher
    else
    {
        string p = get_string("Your text here: ");
        return 0;
    }
  } //end of for loop?  TODO: fix your braces spacing the sample was broken
}//end of for main?  TODO: fix your braces spacing the sample was broken
```

Comment: Hi @Bwebb, thanks for the answer. But now my code prints a new error message error: expected expression else. Any advice for this?

Comment: yeah your curly braces are all over the place, you have many problems with the sample code provided and you will need to fix them all.

Comment: This still has a problem that `string` is not a defined type — the standard C headers included do not define the type.  There is, however, a header `cs50.h` used by the CS50 course that does define `typedef char *string;` — it also declares functions such as `get_string()` which takes a prompt and returns a dynamically allocated string.

Comment: @user71812: In C, an `else` clause can only appear after an `if` statement.  Normally, that means `if (…condition…) { …statements… } else { … statements… }`.  There are various ways that can be varied (a single statement not inside braces is allowed, for example, and the statement after `else` could be another `if (…condition…) …`, etc.  But the key point is that `else` only appears after an `if` and not in any other context. Your `else` has no prior `if` that it can qualify.  Maybe you need `if (argc > 1) { …block of code with for loop etc… } else { …your else clause… }`.  It's hard to guess.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the advice. Yes I am working on the CS50 haha, I guess I missed including the library to the header. But it seems my code still has a lot of probs though. Will try to debug it line by line. thanks anyway!